# Client Certificate is not being passed on by Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-api-management

I've picked up something that someone else has set up.
We have an API Management instance, siting behind an Application Gateway, which has a policy on an API:

```
<inbound>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null)">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="403" reason="Client certificate required..d1PD" />
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(!context.Request.Certificate.Verify())">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="403" reason="Client certificate cannot be verified..d2PD " />
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(!context.Deployment.Certificates.Any(c => c.Value.Thumbprint == context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint))">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="403" reason="Client certificate is untrusted or invalid..d3PD" />
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
        <base />
    </inbound>
```

In Postman I am passing a cert and key. The Postman Console shows

```
Client Certificate:
keyPath:"C:\selfsigned\internalscm.X.com.key"
pemPath:"C:\selfsigned\internalscm.X.com.crt"
pfxPath:""
```

I'm passing `Ocp-Apim-Trace` in the header of the request so am getting a trace back which contains:

```
traceEntries        {2}
  inbound       [10]
..
    6       {4}
        source  :   authentication-certificate
        timestamp   :   2019-08-06T08:55:31.3435485Z
        elapsed :   00:00:00.0006857
            data        {2}
                message :   Certificate was attached to request per configuration.
                certificate     {...}
    7       {4}
        source  :   choose
        timestamp   :   2019-08-06T08:55:31.3435485Z
        elapsed :   00:00:00.0007011
            data        {3}
                message :   Expression was successfully evaluated.
                expression  :   context.Request.Certificate == null
                value   :   true
```

UPDATE:

The `authentication-certificate` assessment is of the backend's certificate and is nothing to do with the client certificate (`.key` and `.crt`) that Postman claims to be including in the request (the same result is returned if I pass a `pfx` and password instead of `.key` and `.crt`).

When I hit the API that the Gateway is protecting, I can see in the trace that it is processing the client certificate (and returning a 200):

```
     {
        "source": "client-certificate-handler",
        "timestamp": "2019-08-09T15:47:46.3825928Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.0005974",
        "data": "Requesting client certificate because next handler requires access to it."
      },
      {
        "source": "client-certificate-handler",
        "timestamp": "2019-08-09T15:47:46.6950495Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.3225172",
        "data": "Client certificate thumbprint '6C03F4E7999999999999999999999999'  received."
      },
      {
        "source": "choose",
        "timestamp": "2019-08-09T15:47:46.6950495Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.3225288",
        "data": {
          "message": "Expression was successfully evaluated.",
          "expression": "context.Request.Certificate == null",
          "value": false
        }
      },
      {
        "source": "choose",
        "timestamp": "2019-08-09T15:47:46.9606395Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.5849700",
        "data": {
          "message": "Expression was successfully evaluated.",
          "expression": "!context.Request.Certificate.Verify()",
          "value": false
        }
      },
      {
        "source": "choose",
        "timestamp": "2019-08-09T15:47:46.9606395Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.5850060",
        "data": {
          "message": "Expression was successfully evaluated.",
          "expression": "!context.Deployment.Certificates.Any(c => c.Value.Thumbprint == context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint)",
          "value": false
        }
      }
```

So it looks like AppGateway is dropping the client certificate.

The trace doesn't give me enough to start deducing why the client certificate (assuming that Postman is transmitting it to the Gateway as it does the API) is being dropped. Where should I start?

For ref, when I remove the policy the request is processed as expected.

Comment: Hi, did you manage do solve this problem ?

Comment: Hi @Tyrannas. As Vitaliy suggested it is not possible. We had to remove that requirement from our project.

Comment: Hi @Badgerspot, the inbound policies you have at the top of the post, since using App Gateway are not valid anymore? I'm in a similar situation. Want to access the thumbprint from client certificate and that doesn't seem possible anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can make AppGateway pass the certificate - you need to check their docs. The reason I'm skeptical is bacuse the whole idea of AppGateway is to look into traffic and provide protection by doing that. And the only way to d othat is to terminate SSL connection at AppGateway level. See here for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ssl-overview there are two modes for AppGateway: SSL temination when AppGateway makes HTTP (not HTTPS) calls to backend, and SSL end-to-end when AppGateway uses own SSL certificate to connect to backend.

Some client certificate information can be passed to backend via server variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#mutual-authentication-server-variables

Comment: Thanks @Vitaliy Kurokhtin . The Azure team told someone in my org it was possible so we have queried that assertion (based upon the links you have supplied). I'll wait to hear back from them (and update this) but it feels like this is the answer.

Comment: Hey there. Is it possible now? Since 2022 Application Gateway V2 supports mutual auth via SSLProfiles. But the problem is they are not forwarded to API Management. Do you know alread a way?

Comment: If AppGateway needs to analyze traffic it has to terminate SSL and by nature of encryption it doesn't have access to client certificate to use it for connection purposes with backend. You can configure end-to-end TLS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ssl-overview but that implies authentication to backend with different certificate. But you can pass some information about client certificate to backend, see server variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#mutual-authentication-server-variables

Comment: Thanks @VitaliyKurokhtin I think for our scenario is it not possible. We only want specific APIs to use mutual auth. So application gateway should require the certificates only for specified paths. Do you see a way for this?

Comment: I think it should be possible as long as you're fine having different hostnames for APIs requiring mutual auth and not. You could try creating two separate SSL profiles one with mutual auth enabled and one without and associate both with same backend pool.

Comment: Hey @VitaliyKurokhtin Yes i tried this already but its ugly. But maybe we need this way... But thanks if there is no other way maybe we stick to a second hostname. Thanks and regards