# Client Certificate Validation at APIM using Application Gateway Mutual authentication server variables

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

I want to implement client certificate validation in Azure API Management policy for certificate

1: Expiration 
2: from specific Issuer 
3: with specific Subject 
4: Revocation ( I see Client Certificate Revocation validation can be done through AppGateway
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/mutual-authentication-overview?tabs=portal#certificate-revocation but its not clear weather its enabled by default )

I have Application gateway in front of API Management service deployed in internal mode connected to vnet so client certificate cannot be passed to API Management so I cannot use `context.Request.Certificate.Verify()` to verify client certificate.

I came across [Application Gateway Mutual authentication server variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#mutual-authentication-server-variables)

| Variable name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| client_certificate | The client certificate in PEM format for an established SSL connection. |
| client_certificate_end_date | The end date of the client certificate. |
| client_certificate_fingerprint | The SHA1 fingerprint of the client certificate for an established SSL connection. |
| client_certificate_issuer | The "issuer DN" string of the client certificate for an established SSL connection. |
| client_certificate_serial | The serial number of the client certificate for an established SSL connection. |
| client_certificate_start_date | The start date of the client certificate. |
| client_certificate_subject | The "subject DN" string of the client certificate for an established SSL connection. |
| client_certificate_verification | The result of the client certificate verification: SUCCESS, FAILED:, or NONE if a certificate was not present. |

So is there any easy way to set `context.Request.Certificate` to use `context.Request.Certificate.Verify()` or [validate-client-certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-client-certificate-policy) polic

to do various checks on Client Certificate using [Application Gateway Mutual authentication server variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#mutual-authentication-server-variables)

Some of the related articles which I have found are below.

[client certificate validation on APIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68040404/client-certificate-validation-on-apim) 
[Client Certificate is not being passed on by Azure Application Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372611/client-certificate-is-not-being-passed-on-by-azure-application-gateway) 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/549967/api-management-forwarded-client-certificate-valida

Answer (score 2):

There may be a few caveats depending on how exactly certificate is presented in `client_certificate` server variable, but as long as you use AppGateway rewrite functionality to pass it to APIM, say in a header, you should be able to achieve this by writing a policy:

```
<choose>
    <when condition="@{
        var pem = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("client_certificate");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pem))
        {
            return true;
        }

        X509Certificate2 cert;
        try
        {
            // Removing '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----' and '-----END CERTIFICATE-----' if those are present
            pem = string.Join(string.Empty, pem.Split('\n').Where(s => !s.StartsWith("---")));

            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pem);
            cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
        }
        catch
        {
            return true;
        }

        return !cert.Verify();
    }">
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized" />
        </return-response>
    </when>
</choose>
```